# Guessing Mathematical Probabilities by Tests

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

I'm stuck with a (maybe simple) problem.

I have 4 values possible for a test, and I can do as many tests as I want.

What is the minimum number of tests required to be at least at 95% sure I have the right probability for each value?

Is it even possible to guess ?

Thanks by advance,

Comment: The minimum number depends on the actual PDF which you are required to calculate. So it's a chicken-egg paradox IMO, there's no way to determine that number before you know what the PDF is.

Comment: There is a number of [Monte-Carlo methods for confidence intervals](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=tIsjh56pI0IC&pg=PA104&lpg=PA104&dq=monte+carlo+confidence+interval+nonlinear+regression&source=bl&ots=dQZztqdWP5&sig=TiTZa3p2UYf6vM_jjcstTKdKQQ4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiE7cj1gPPMAhVoCpoKHbEdAV8Q6AEIOjAE#v=onepage&q=monte%20carlo%20confidence%20interval%20nonlinear%20regression&f=false), may be you can search somewhere in this direction (e.g. plotting confidence intervals for each bar of the histogram and comparing with your estimated or theoretical density).

Comment: You can monitor the speed of convergence of such an interval, for example stop when it doesn't seem to change much. However, I can be wrong, this is just my idea how to approach this.